# problems with projecting Galileo images of Europa (the moon) images in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am working on a project where I will be using Galileo images. Since I would like to look at the same feature from multiple different angles (something Galileo has taken images of), I would like to be able to upload the images (which are .tiff files) into QGIS and arrange them by latitude so that I can see the ones that overlap, and mark the areas of interest to my study.

But the images are not compatible with the default CRS system so, QGIS will display the layers only if I zoom to them individually, and I cannot view more than one at once.
I did change the project CRS to IGNF:EUROPA54, but I got an error message saying "No transform available between IGNF:EUROPA54 and ESRI:104915. I don't know what I've done wrong if anything.
(Note: I do know Python but that's it, I have hardly any experience in QGIS)

for reference, I got these images from here: https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/map/Europa/Mosaic/Equirectangular_Mosaics_of_Europa_v3
the article says "The final bundle solution used constraints of 500 m in radius and 1 degree on camera angles. We adjusted the orientation of Europa (parameterized as the prime meridian offset W_o) to ensure the data are aligned with the IAU-defined coordinate system for Europa (i.e., the longitude of the crater Cilix must be at 182 degrees west, or 178 degrees east)"

Comment: QGIS 3.30 shows a rather long list or IAU CRSs with filter "Europa". I would try those first.

Comment: all of the ones I saw were for Europe, the continent on Earth, and when I searched IAU in the search bar, I got no results.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS supports celestial bodies (see https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/43150)

Unfortunately I am not familiar with planetary data but at least I do see a lot of entries for "Europa" in my user interface. An example about one entry in a screenshot below. The map preview seems to be Earth-only so don't pay attention to that.

[image]